# How do I instruct R to install all Bioconductor packages that are not already installed?

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

Apparently installing all Bioconductor packages is not that troublesome

### install all Bioconductor software packages

biocLite(all_group())

However if you want to install only those packages that are not available and installed on your computer then what is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fairly easily work with

```
IP <- installed.packages()
```

and

```
AP <- available.packages()
```

and then feed these into `setdiff()` to compute differences.

Comment: thank you @Dirk. Your solution worked great!

`IP <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())`

`AP <- as.data.frame(available.packages())`

`install.packages(setdiff(AP[,1],IP[,1]))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful about just installing the differences in BioConductor.  I've encountered the situations where I initially installed package `A.1` which depends on `B.1`.  Weeks or months later I install package `C.2` which depends on `B.2`.

Keep in mind that BioConductor *only* keeps the most up to date versions of packages available. This means that `B.1` is no longer available via BioConductor. So `R` in its infinite wisdom, will happily clobber your previous install of `B.1` with `B.2`, *breaking* the functionality of `A.1` and turning your whole installation into a hot mess.

To mitigate this issue, I'd recommend installing the packages you want to use all at once.  Using the most recent version of R (which is 3.6.0 right now) E.g.

```
# Install into directory of your choosing.
# Be sure to appropriately set .libPaths in your .Rprofile
.libPaths = .libPaths("/some/local/path/3.6.0-lib_all_bioc") 

install.packages("BiocManager")
library(BiocManager)
repos = BiocManager::available()
BiocManager::install(repos)
```

Keep in mind that the [instructions](http://bioconductor.org/install/) for installing BioConductor have changed recently (in the last year or two).